# Are we "allowed" to use methods on JavaScript maps (the data type) and if so are there any new rules?

Tags: javascript, methods, map, factory

JavaScript maps (the data type, not the array method) seem set up to accept data (key/value pairs) but not necessarily methods. At least they're not advertised that way. However, we *can* put methods onto a map instance. Intriguingly, the keyword `this` works in such methods, and returns the map itself. For example:

```
const m = new Map();
m.set('key1', 'value1');
m.get('key1'); // returns 'value1', i.e. standard map usage
m.methodA = function(x) {console.log(x + ' to you too');};
m.methodA('hello'); // shows 'hello to you too'
m.methodB = function() {console.log(this.get('key1'));};
m.methodB(); // shows 'value1'
```

Is this a proper use of maps and/or methods within maps and/or `this` within methods within maps? Or am I corrupting something somehow or breaking some rules by doing this? It seems fairly straight forward and reasonable, making me think it should be OK, but I've never seen or heard anything about this before which makes me nervous.

I can't create a map with a constructor the way I can create an object with a constructor. However, I can create a map factory to produce maps of a given "type". For example, I can use a factory to create maps of the "car type". I can thus also attach methods to each map of this "type" by including them in the factory:

```
const createCarMap = function(features) {
  const carMap = new Map(features);
  carMap.set('# tires', 'four (assumed)');
  carMap.speakersAreFeatured = function() {
    return this.has('speakers');
  };
  return carMap;
};
const yourCar = createCarMap([
  ['# cylinders', 'twelve'],
  ['speakers', 'awesome']
]);
const myCar = createCarMap([
  ['exterior', 'pearly white']
]);
yourCar.speakersAreFeatured(); // returns true
myCar.speakersAreFeatured();   // returns false
```

However, such a method will be attached repeatedly for every map produced. This is in contrast to how methods can be added to an object's prototype, allowing method re-usability. So, can methods be attached to a map in a way that allows method re-usability?

My more general question is: Should we be using methods on maps. If so, how? Should we think of them and use them essentially the same way we do with objects, or are there "new rules" for using them with maps? (I suppose one could ask similar questions about other new-ish data types too, e.g. sets, weakMaps, etc., but I'm limiting myself here to maps.)

Comment: You can add methods to *any* Javascript object, Maps are not special in this

Comment: @Caleth, thanks for suggesting to me that adding methods to maps is a "normal JavaScript-y" way of doing things. That does address one of my earlier questions. One of my other questions still remains though: in my example, the `speakersAreFeatured` method is added separately to both `yourCar` and `myCar`...is there a way of re-using such a method, like you can when you attach a method not to an object but to an object prototype?

Comment: @AndrewWillems - again, Maps aren't special.  You can subclass Map and create objects using your subclass (at least, [you can assuming you're using ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900954/why-isnt-map-subclassable-in-chrome-node)).

Comment: ... and there's an actual solution for how to do it in current browsers here: http://www.2ality.com/2013/03/subclassing-builtins-es6.html

Comment: @Jules, it'll take me some time to get my head around Raushmayer's blog that you link to, but it sounds both relevant and intriguing. Combining your comment about subclassing Map with the content of his article, are you saying that I can use `class CarMap extends Map {...}`? If so, I'm not yet clear on how to: build the constructor, use `super.call(...)`, create the actual map (if that's different than `super.call(...)`, attach my `speakersAreFeatured` method, etc. It would be great if you could put together an example as an answer, tho' I understand that that might be a lot of work.

Comment: For others who might be interested: The [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-map-constructor) states: "The Map constructor is designed to be subclassable. It may be used as the value in an extends clause of a class definition. Subclass constructors that intend to inherit the specified Map behaviour must include a super call to the Map constructor to create and initialize the subclass instance with the internal state necessary to support the  Map.prototype built-in methods."

Comment: @Jules, inspired by your comments, I dug deeper and discovered how to subclass Map. See my additional answer that shows how I implemented this for my `CarMap` example. In retrospect I understand why both you and @Caleth emphasized that Maps aren't special (as the final solution looks very much like a normal ES6 class that uses `extends`), but this was not obvious to me when I started looking into this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by comments from @Jules after the original question, I figured out the following: If you are using ES6, you can create a new class that extends the built-in Map data type. The constructor should pass any needed parameters to a `super` call, creating the map and placing it in `this`. Then, any code within the class that needs to use the map, either in the constructor or in any of its methods, just uses `this`.

```
class CarMap extends Map {
    constructor(features) {
        super(features);
        this.set('# tires', 'four (assumed)');
    }
    speakersAreFeatured() {
        return this.has('speakers');
    }
}

const yourCar = new CarMap([
  ['# cylinders', 'twelve'],
  ['speakers', 'awesome']
]);

const myCar = new CarMap([
  ['exterior', 'pearly white']
]);

console.log(yourCar.speakersAreFeatured()); // --> true
console.log(myCar.speakersAreFeatured());   // --> false
```

Answer (score 0):

(Changing from comment to answer)

Why don't you extend `Map` with:

```
Map.prototype.speakersAreFeatured = function() {
    return this.has('speakers');
};
```

This will define it for all instance of Map.

Comment: Interesting idea. However, I don't want to extend _all_ maps with that method, only my so-called carMaps.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: This solution does work and, as far as I can tell, doesn't break any rules. However, it is an older ES5-like solution to the problem. See my other answer for a more ES6-like solution.**

I suppose one solution would be to bury the map within a normal object as one of that object's properties (e.g. `mapObj`) and then attach the methods to that object rather than to the map itself. Then have the map-specific methods refer to the map as a property of the parent object, i.e. refer to `this.mapObj` rather than simply `this`. This seems a little convoluted/hacky as the only purpose of the parent object (instantiated from the `Car` class in the example below) is to allow for code re-use of the methods, but at least it does just that.

*(Just to clarify a choice of variable name below: In the example below I call the property that contains the map `mapObj` instead of just `map` because the latter could be confusing as there is already a standard `map` method on arrays that this might otherwise get mixed up with.)*

In the example below, the `Car` class passes the `features` into an internal map factory. Then, note the difference between the two variations of the body of the `speakersAreFeatured` method:

- as shown in the question: `return this.has('speakers');`
- as shown in the code below: `return this.mapObj.has('speakers');`

Code:

```
class Car {
  constructor(features) {
    this.mapObj = this.createCarMap(features);
  }
  createCarMap(features) {
    const carMap = new Map(features);
    carMap.set('# tires', 'four (assumed)');
    return carMap;
  }
  speakersAreFeatured() {
    return this.mapObj.has('speakers');
  }
}

const yourCar = new Car([
  ['# cylinders', 'twelve'],
  ['speakers', 'awesome']
]);
const myCar = new Car([
  ['exterior', 'pearly white']
]);
yourCar.speakersAreFeatured(); // returns true
myCar.speakersAreFeatured();   // returns false
```

Comment: While the comments after the original question contain important discussion about how to solve this problem using more modern ES6 approaches, the approach in this answer seems to have been suggested by [at least one other person](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900954/why-isnt-map-subclassable-in-chrome-node) who says that one pre-ES6 way to extend maps is to use a "Factory/constructor [which] makes objects with an internal Map instance that you delegate to" which is, as I understand it, what I tried to do in this answer.